# Trying to send bulk invitations to a yammer group

Tags: yammer, bulk-email

We are trying to send mail invitations to multiple users from our web application to join Yammer network using API https://developer.yammer.com/docs/invitations.json but by using this we are able to send at most to 20 mail ids at a time. 
Is there any other way to send bulk mails for more than 20 ids at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the Yammer rate throttling is going to stand in your way, and there's nothing you can do to change it. The best you can hope to do is implement some kind of delay that tries to time the windows when you can send, and make sure to process, delay, and re-submit any 429 (too many requests) responses you get.